# Pass variable to PhpUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I developed a set of test cases using phpunit used for testing both development site and the production site. The only difference is the domain name. How can I pass the domain from command line to phpunit test cases so that I do not need to modify every file?

Comment: Can the test load it from some kind of configuration file?

Answer (score 12):

In your `phpunit-bootstrap.php` you can do something like this:

```
$site = getenv('DOMAIN');
```

and use

```
<php>
  <env name="DOMAIN" value="http://production.com"/>
</php>
```

in your `phpunit.xml` file [**as shown in the documentation**](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html).

The downside of this approach is that you need to have two different `xml` files.

---

Other options are using a custom wrapper script around phpunit like @DavidHarkness showed which tends to work out well

or, if you don't want to run those tests in an automated way (or use both approaches) to do something like:

```
$site = getenv('DOMAIN');
if(!$site) {
    echo "Enter Domain: ";
    $site = fgets(STDIN);
}
```

and have the runner check the environment and if nothing is there ask you for the domain.

---

#### Env or define or anything else

The same goes for pretty much every way that php can take in input from the outside world.

```
<php>
  <define name="DOMAIN" value="http://production.com"/>
</php>
```

also works in case you are using a constant anyways, for example.

Answer (score 4):

You could set an environment variable before running the tests. To make this easier on yourself, create a simple script to export the variable and run the tests.

```
#!/bin/bash

USAGE="Usage: $0 <domain> [file-or-directory]"

if [ "$#" == "0" ]; then
    echo "$USAGE"
    exit 1
fi

export TEST_DOMAIN=$1
shift
phpunit $*
```

In your base test case you can access this value using [`getenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php):

```
$domain = getenv('TEST_DOMAIN');
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. One way you can do this with `bash` is to export the ENV variables you want to pass in and chain the phpunit call using `;` like so:

```
#: HOST_NAME="my.host.com"; phpunit MyTestFile.php
```

That will create a `HOST_NAME` environment variable and then immediately call your unit test.

Then within your test script you can access the `HOST_NAME` variable using something like:

```
$host = getenv('HOST_NAME');
```