# Parallelize functional tests while using a SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, symfony, phpunit, parallel-testing, liipfunctionaltestbundle

I have added many tests in my Symfony2 project, but now with 53 tests and 176 assertions it takes about a minute. I'm trying to reduce this time because if I enable code coverage report it takes 15 minutes.

> $ phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist PHPUnit 4.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>  
>   Configuration read from app/phpunit.xml.dist
>   .....................................................
>   Time: 59.1 seconds, Memory: 361.00Mb
>   OK (53 tests, 176 assertions)

I've configured [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle) correctly to use a SQLite database in the `test` environment (this is recommended by [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle#sqlite)):

<kbd>app/config/config_test.yml</kbd>

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_sqlite
                path:     %kernel.cache_dir%/test.db
```

And I've added fixtures with [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

Now I have to create [tests suites](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.testsuites) or [groups](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.groups) to launch several instances of PHPUnit. But I'm seeing a future problem: how can tests can be parallelized (for example with [paratest](https://github.com/brianium/paratest)) if two or more instances of phpunit write and read data in the same SQLite file?

I can [Pass a variable to PhpUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8491437/2257664) to change the `kernel.cache_dir` value and create one `cache` directory per phpunit instance. But it can't be done from the command line, so if I choose this solution I'll have to create several `phpunit.xml.dist`. I'm looking for a more convenient solution.

Comment: 53 functional tests in one minute? I don't think there is any performance problem. Besides, IMO code coverage should be used only for unit tests.

Comment: @gontrollez can you please explain briefly what do you mean by *unit tests*? Are they targeted tests which focus on a few pages, functions, etc. Do you suggest to run code coverage analysis only once a day for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround by creating as many cache directories as test files.

I defined 8 test suites to fit with the 8 cores of my CPU:

```
<!-- app/phpunit.xml.dist -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit
    backupGlobals = "false"
    …
>
    …
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Group1">
            <file>../src/AcmeBundle/Tests/Command/CommandTest.php</file>
            <file>…</file>
        </testsuite>
        …
        <testsuite name="Group8">
            <file>../src/AcmeBundle/Tests/Controller/AdminControllerTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

I created a <kbd>phpunit.sh</kbd> script which use `export` (as suggested by [David Harkness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494759/2257664) in order to define a specific path for each test suite:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function test() {
    testsuite=$1
    export CACHE_PATH="$testsuite"
    OUTPUT=$(phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist --testsuite $testsuite)
    RETURN=$?
    if [ $RETURN -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -e -n "\033[01;32m●  OK\t\033[00m \033[01;35m$testsuite\033[00m"
        tail=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | tail -n 3)
        echo -e "\t\"$tail\"" | tr '\n' '\t' | tr -s '\t'
        echo ""
    else
        echo -e "\033[01;31m❌  ERROR\033[00m \033[01;35m$testsuite\033[00m (\033[01;34m$RETURN\033[00m)\033[00m"
        echo "-----"
        echo "$OUTPUT"
        echo "-----"
    fi
}

for testsuite in $(seq 1 8)
do
    tester "Group$testsuite" &
done

# http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231602/how-to-detect-that-all-the-child-processes-launched-in-a-script-ended/231608#231608
wait

echo "Done"
```

Successful test suites are displayed with with green marks if everything is OK, and the output of phpunit will be truncated to keep a small output. If there is an error it will be displayed.

Then I added this to <kbd>app/AppKernel.php</kbd>:

```php
/**
 * @see http://symfony.com/fr/doc/2.3/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#surcharger-le-repertoire-cache
 */
public function getCacheDir()
{
    $cachePath = getenv('CACHE_PATH');

    if (
        ($this->environment == 'test')
        &&
        (! empty($cachePath))
    ) {
        return(parent::getCacheDir().'/'.$cachePath.'/');
    }

    # else

    return parent::getCacheDir();
}
```

This code will tell Symfony to create a sub-directory in the cache folder, meaning than multiple instances of PHPUnit won't use the same SQLite file.

---

While it works, this solution is not perfect and have some drawbacks:

- it recreates the entire cache even if I only wanted to change the path of the SQLite database
- it will use space and take time to create one cache per rest file, I suggest you to avoid this if you don't use the RAM as a cache (my solution is to delete <kbd>cache</kbd> in <kbd>app/</kbd> and create a symlink: `ln -s /run/shm/project/cache cache`, tests are faster because caching is done in RAM and not on the hard drive)

Comment: I discovered fastest recently, it's easier to use: https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/blob/master/fastest.md

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bundle](https://github.com/liuggio/fastest) that facilitates parallel test runs with symfony. It can also be used with regular databases, not just sqlite. Unfortunately, it also displays one PHPUnit result per test file. But it only starts as many tests in parallel as your processor can actually execute at the same time, and it also seems to solve the cache problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. paratest has been added to [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/pull/253) (the bundle I use for my tests), it may be an alternative. I'll have to update my answer because I have changed my script, it now launch 8 [test suites](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration) (one per core of my computer) instead of passing all the files.