# Allow PHPUnit test to access ACTUAL environment variable

Tags: php, phpunit, environment-variables, travis-ci

I'm running phpunit in Travis-CI and for security reasons some sensitive information is stored in environment variable.

Currently $_ENV only contains values I am specifying in `phpunit.xml`.

I want my unit tests to be able to access this specific environment variable without storing it in file or passing it as argument.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491437/pass-variable-to-phpunit

Comment: no, it's exact opposite. Besides, since 2014 PHPunit wipes environment before executing scripts and the answer is from '13